# String deleting

Tags: python, regex, string, regex-negation

hope someone could help me. I am new to python and just learning.  I would like to know how to delete unwanted characters from a string.

For example,

I have some strings in a text file such as 'dogs op care 6A domain, cats op pv=2 domain 3, pig op care2 domain 3'

I don't need anything after that starts with op. i.e., what I would like to get is just 'dogs, cats, pig'

I see 'op' as the pattern in all these strings and therefore tried the below code

```
import re
f = open('animalsop.txt','r')
s = f.read()
p = re.compile('op')
match = p.search(s)
print (s[:match.start()])
```

The output I get is just 'dog'

why do I not get the cat and pig as well since they contain 'op' too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated because I would the code to analyse a huge similar data I have got.

The above code was derived from [String splitting in Python using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543480/string-splitting-in-python-using-regex)

credits to Varuna and kragniz

Comment: I'd suggest using dr jimbob's answer since some other answers here might break depending on input. For example, if you have a sentence that says `dog opportunities`, some answers here may break. dr jimbob's looks for spaces on either side. If you do use regex, you should use `\bop\b`, which ensures that what precedes/followed `op` is a non-word character (not `a-zA-Z0-9_`), or ` op ` which does pretty much what dr jimbob's answer does but in regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easiest to not use regular expressions to solve your problem.

Assuming a file named `animalsop.txt` that looks like:

```
dogs op care 6A domain
cats op pv=2 domain 3
pig op care2 domain 3
```

A pythonic solution to your problem would be something like:

```
with open('animalsop.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        before_op = line.split(' op ')[0]
        print(before_op)
```

The nice thing about the `with` construct for opening files in python is that it ensures that you close the file when you are done.

If instead, your `animalsop.txt` file is just one long line with various clauses separated by commas like:

```
dogs op care 6A domain, cats op pv=2 domain 3, pig op care2 domain 3
```

Then you could do something like:

```
with open('animalsop.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for clause in line.split(','):
            before_op = clause.strip().split(' op')[0]
            print(before_op)
```

(The `clause.strip()` removes whitespace if it's present after the comma).

Comment: Hi drjimbob, many thanks for the code. I did try that but the output looks like

Comment: dog op, cat op, pig op

Comment: any suggestions how I could have just have dog, cat, pig without the 'op'. Many thanks

Comment: I am sorry if I have confused, but when I try the code, it returns only 'dog' and not the cat and pig. Am I doing anything wrong here please

Comment: @Tikku - are you sure?  If I have a file that consists of three lines: `dogs op care 6A domain`, `cats op pv=2 domain 3`, `pig op care2 domain 3` inside a file called `animalsop.txt`, and you paste the code snippet above, you'll get `dogs`, `cats`, and `pig` on three separate lines.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. Apologise. The text file I had was not in three separate lines one below the other but instead in a single line separated by commas. However when I put them line by line they work. Thanks for that. But I need to extract the same result from a huge text file where the strings are separated by only commas.

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS :-)

Comment: Thanks very much for all your help and time

Comment: with open('animalsop.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for clause in line.split(','):
            before_op = clause.strip().split(' op')[0]
            print(before_op) #this worked in the end

Answer (score 1):

Based on examples you have provided I suggest to use simple .split() string method and select first part - e.g. part before " op".

```
partOfYourInterest = "dogs op care 6A domain".split(" op")[0]
```

for more you can iterate e.g. via for loop

```
text = ["dogs op care 6A domain","cats op pv=2 domain 3", "pig op care2 domain 3"]

for part in text:
    animal = part.split(" op")[0]
    print(animal)
```

And for your txt it could be like

```
with open('animalsop.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
       animal = part.split(" op")[0]
       print(animal)
```

Comment: Good solution @Petr Matuska

Comment: Many thanks Petr Matuska. I tried the code and I got exactly what I wanted however, I am wondering how to get the strings such as this within quotes. It was easier to type text = ["dogs op care 6A domain","cats op pv=2 domain 3", "pig op care2 domain 3"], but could suggest how I could put this in a huge text file. Many thanks

Comment: Yes, you can open and read you txt file and process it line by line - I edit my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a regular expression you can use:

```
re.findall('\w+?(?= op)', s)

['dogs', 'cats', 'pig']
```

Comment: thanks Evan for you kind code. its easier when I can pick up dogs, cats and pig however when I use large data sets I wondering how to pick them.

Comment: The regex will work with any dataset, it just looks for the word before "op"

Answer (score 0):

if you only want the first word, you can use
if string is your string

```
string='dog fgfdggf fgs, cat afgfg, pig fggag'
strings=string.split(', ')
newstring=strings[0].split(' ', 1)[0]
for stri in strings[1:]:
    newstring=newstring+', '+stri.split(' ', 1)[0]
```